# Difference between GlobalPlatform and EMV

Tags: java, payment, javacard, emv, globalplatform

I am trying to understand the difference between EMV and GlobalPlatform. However, this 2 terms seems to be very abstract and I find it hard to differentiate between or at least understand what is the purpose of them.

To my understanding, EMV represents a set of specifications made by different entities(live Visa, Mastercard etc.) so that the CAD/POSes can communicate with cards. This means, that whoever is implementing a certain applet that will be deployed on a card needs to respect the above specification, so every CAD can understand what the card is returning, and also the card will understand what the CAD is asking for.

On the other hand, GP represents a set of specifications/rules that needs to be enforced on a card level so that the card is safe and compliant. Meaning that the entity that is issuing the card should implement this new functionalities, or at least have them available. For example, NXP is developing PN81T that runs JCOP 4, JCOP4 or the chip itself need to implement the rules enforced by GP, so everything is safe when using the card.

I am probably wrong, so that is why I ask these questions here, I just want to truly understand these terms.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For EMV you are right, what it defines is the interface and some operational things. Globalplatform defines a large set of specifications. The one you are referring to is the card specification, basically defining how to install and manage applications, e.g. the EMV one on a smart card. I have written an article which should be useful [Global Platform](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/globalPlatformSpecification.html).

Comment: So, GP only enforces certain rules so that the card as whole is secured? Rules regarding the installation/management/deletion of the applets or how different keys are handled in order to make the smart card secured?

Comment: Also, thanks for the link, will dive into it soon :D

Comment: @KropiusDop: I would not name it rules, it defines the behavior and mechanism. Based on your EMV example if you look at the available specifications https://globalplatform.org you see the card specification and the "CARD FINANCIAL CONFIGURATION" which defines a subset of the card specification which have to be implemented by the payment card.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks a lot!